# Reading a raw RAM data in python

Tags: python, ram

I took the dump of RAM data using a freeware called DumpIt(http://www.downloadcrew.com/article/23854-dumpit). The software saved the RAM data as a raw file which can be read using a Hex Editor(http://www.downloadcrew.com/article/10814-hxd).
How do I get the string data as visible in the Hex Editor(see image) in python?
 [image: snapshot of Hex editor]

For eg: I want to get the string "**http://www.downloadcrew.com/article/23854-dumpit**" in red box in image in python by reading the raw file generated by DumpIt.

**EDIT**

I tried using this code but it just gets stalled and nothing happens

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import binascii
filename = "LEMARC-20140401-181003.raw"
g = open("out","w")
str=""
with open(filename,"rb") as f:
    for lines in f:
        str+=lines
str = binascii.unhexlify(str)
f.close()
g.write(str)
g.close
```

Comment: It sounds like the file is not encoded in hexadecimal, which would make your title misleading.

Comment: @DanGetz: Completely true. If you just open the file normally (using Notepad, for example), the text in the red box will be readable as-is. So you can just open the file in Python the usual way, using `open`.

Comment: @JohnY, It wont be readable in notepad, it shows weird characters when opened directly into a notepad just like a binary file.

Comment: @lemarc Readable enough to be able to extract the wanted string.

Answer (score 2):

In Python2

```
"437c2123".decode('hex')
'C|!#'
```

In Python3 (also works in Python2, for <2.6 you can't have the b prefixing the string)

```
import binascii
binascii.unhexlify(b"437c2123")
b'C|!#'
```

So in your case decode the entire hex string to get the ascii, and then you can extract the url with a regex or your own parsing function